# Can I use 444RGB or 555RGB in python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

I'm using 24b RGB format (888, 8bits for each color) with below pillow.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new(( 'RGB', (360,360), "black")

pixels = img.load()
img.show()
```

Can I use 444RGB or 555RGB in python as well? I can't find the right way to deal the compacted RGB format. Please give me an advice. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean? It is ok just to transform a RGB444 to RGB888 and then you work normally, or you want to work with a RGB444?

Comment: What's the bigger picture please? I mean what are you planning to write the images to - a display? Some RGB444 file format? What sort of algorithms/processing do you want to use?

Comment: Guys, I don't want to transform. I just want to play on the RGB444 or RGB555 world, instead of RGB888 world. 
Especially, I just want to test alpha-blend (figure on the figure with transparency.)

Comment: No. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

Comment: OK. Pillow seems not to support RGB444. How about other image processing engine in python? I hope the other engine can support...

Comment: Pillow supports "paletted" (`P` mode) images, so you _can_ effectively have 444 or 555 bits-per-pixel images because both have less than 256 colors (64 and 125 respectively).

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look the paletted. One question: what's the meaning of 64 and 125? 444 has 2^12 levels, 555 has 2^15 levels. Isn't it?